# Blend for Visual Studioで作成したWPFアプリがbinから出すと動かない

Tags: wpf

Blend for Visual Studio 2017 で作成した WPFアプリが、
Blend から実行した場合と、（プロジェクト名）/bin/Release/ の .exe をそのまま起動した場合には期待通り動作するのですが、
bin/Release 内から .exe 等を別の場所（デスクトップなど）へ移動すると、起動させても何も起こらなくなってしまいました。

移動したファイルですが、Release フォルダ内に存在したものは .dll や .xml など全てを含みます。
また、Debug ビルドで生成した際にも同じ現象となります。

上記の情報だけでは不十分かと思いますが、何を提供すべきかも全く判らないレベルのため、必要なものを仰っていただければ追加いたします。

Answer (score 0):

日本語が含まれるパスに置いていたら起動しないという、非常に初歩的なミスでした。
Windows・Blend とも日本語の環境で使っていて、そんなことは無いだろうという先入観がありました。

何故こうなるのかは依然として不明ですが、心当たりがあるとすれば今回初めて導入した Realm でしょうか・・・。